# do not get response data with firebase database rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I do not get any return from firebase realtime database after adding a rule for my table of quotes. I expect all quotes to be returned where the auth.uid matches the owner value of the quote. However i get nothing.

Can anyone hep me out?

The rules are specified as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"     
    },
    "quotes":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "data.child('owner').val() === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the quotes table is structured as follows:

```
{
  "1ec658d2-a7cb-45b8-8d9b-9c2a6783365d" : {
    "dateCreated" : "2019-12-02T16:06:50+01:00",
    "owner" : "DVRVSpeOXQV6wAmHAdpAe6iPQ5i2",
    "ownerName" : "testOost",
    "projectName" : "testProject1"
  },
  "96549b51-6356-4c37-a388-592561394d1a" : {
    "dateCreated" : "2019-09-25T14:58:13+02:00",
    "owner" : "xZBFCq4ho3V2G8dZTvK7RjsnTr43",
    "ownerName" : "timcastelijn",
    "projectName" : "testProject2"
  }
}
```

my code to access the data is

```
this.props.firebase.db.ref('quotes/').on('value', snapshot => {
  const quotesObject = snapshot.val();

  /* quotesObject is handled here */

});
```

## UPDATE:SOLVED

the issue was solved with @frank-van-puffelen 's solution.

the new rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"     
    },
    "quotes":{
      ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
                query.orderByChild == 'owner' &&
                query.equalTo == auth.uid" // restrict basket access to owner of quote
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the new snippet:

```
this.props.firebase.db.ref('quotes/').orderByChild("owner")
             .equalTo(this.authUser.uid)
             .on("value", snapshot => {

  const quotesObject = snapshot.val();

  ....

});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to read from `/quotes`, but your rules allow no-one to read from `/quotes`. So the rules reject the read operation.

Keep in mind:

- Rules don't filter data, instead they merely enforce the access rules.
- If you want to only allow a user to read their own data, your code and rules need to work together to allow that.

In your current use-case you can simply modify the code to only read the node for that specific user:

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
this.props.firebase.db.ref('quotes/'+uid).on('value', snapshot => {
  const quotesObject = snapshot.val();

  /* quotesObject is handled here */

});
```

In other cases, you'll want to use a query in your code, and then validate that query in the rules.

For more on these see:

- The documentation on [rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)
- The documentation on [securing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules)
- Other questions about [rules are not filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). One thing to keep in mind when reading these is that many of these may have been answered before it was possible to secure queries, so their answers may be outdated.

Comment: hi @frank-van-puffelen, thanks for your response. I got it working with your suggestion on queries. However, I realized I was actually trying to create a filter, to show data to its owner, but also to a user with an ADMIN role. Do you have a suggestion to achieve that maybe?